# Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy issue after resurrecting website

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs

I started a website a couple of years ago, and just in the process of updating it. However, I am now getting:

> The Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy header has been ignored, because the
> URL's origin was untrustworthy. It was defined either in the final
> response or a redirect. Please deliver the response using the HTTPS
> protocol. You can also use the 'localhost' origin instead. See
> https://www.w3.org/TR/powerful-features/#potentially-trustworthy-origin
> and
> https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#the-cross-origin-opener-policy-header.

Is this a problem with my code, or has something changed in recent browsers that prevent my older code from working?

I am using a React JS front end with PHP API backend.

I also have links to various libraries such as:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href='/smartmenus-1.1.0/css/sm-core-css.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
<link href='/smartmenus-1.1.0/css/sm-blue/sm-blue.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
<link href="/resources/css/sm_styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/resources/js/DragDropTouch.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/resources/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/resources/js/popper.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/resources/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/smartmenus-1.1.0/jquery.smartmenus.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/smartmenus-1.1.0/addons/bootstrap-4/jquery.smartmenus.bootstrap-4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.5.3/jspdf.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Some of those have crossorigin parameters, so I'm not sure if it's those that could be causing the issue.

What specifically is the cause of my problem? Does it have to do with the React side, the PHP side, or one of the 3rd party libraries I'm linking to? How do I go about fixing this issue?

Comment: So generally Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy header issues are due to changes in browser security policies, specifically related to cross-origin security. So make sure your PHP server includes appropriate CORS headers to allow requests from your React frontend. Also check if there are any specific configurations in your React application or in your browser that might be affecting these security policies. Some browser extensions or configurations could impact cross-origin policies. Lastly also check if any 3rd party library you are linking, might not be served over HTTPS anymore.